# reCAPTCHA on Android?

Tags: android, httpclient, recaptcha

I was wondering how I use reCAPTCHA with my Android app? Right now, I am stuck, I can get the HTML code using an HttpClient request but I do not know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with implementing capchas. But to me it seems like you'd want to pass your html string in to a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) with a call like this:

```
wv.loadData(htmlStr,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Does anyone know if there is another way that is similar to reCAPTCHA on the Android?

Answer (score 1):

[reCaptcha android library](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha.html) will solve your problem.

it's part of google play services.